# powershell connection not opening

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I am using powershell to query sql Server.
This is the code I am using, it's simple code:

```
@echo on

set svr=ax-riscvmssql18\SQL18
set dbname=master

set $cn2 = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=ax-riscvmssql18\SQL18;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=master");

$cn2.Open()
```

It gives me an error:

```
E:\utility\batfiles>$cn2.Open()
'$cn2.Open' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Are you trying to put PowerShell code directly in batch file?

Comment: iam putting code in .cmd files and running through command prompt

Comment: It would not work this way. CMD can not run PowerShell code.

Comment: how can i  use it iam saving in .cmd files and running through comand prompt. I have to use Pwershell to execute scripts what should be extension of files if i want to use in command prompt

Comment: i need to query sql server from powershell, and same i need in txt files

Answer (score 2):

In powershell your code would be like this:

```
$svr="ax-riscvmssql18\SQL18"
$dbname="master"

$cn2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
#$cn2.ConnectionString = "Server=$svr;uid=$user; pwd=$pwd; Database=$dbname; Integrated Security=False;"
$cn2.ConnectionString = "Server = $svr; Database = $dbname; Integrated Security = True" 

$cn2.Open()
```

Save this as anything-you-want.ps1 and run it from a powershell console/ise.

Comment: PS E:\utility\batfiles> DBAEnvProd.ps1
The term 'DBAEnvProd.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:15
+ DBAEnvProd.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DBAEnvProd.ps1:String) [], Comm
   andNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Suggestion [3,General]: The command DBAEnvProd.ps1 was not found, but does exist
 in the current location. Windows PowerShell doesn't load commands from the curr
ent location by default. If you trust this command, instead type ".\DBAEnvProd.p
s1". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.
PS E:\utility\batfiles>

Comment: Just follow the Suggestion. In PS you call a script by providing a path:  `.\scriptname.ps1`, if in current directory.

Comment: i did that ps: .\scriptname.ps1. this error iam gettingPS E:\utility\batfiles> .\DBAEnvProd.ps1

Comment: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishin
g a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Loc
ating Server/Instance Specified)"
At E:\utility\batfiles\DBAEnvProd.ps1:7 char:10
+ $cn2.Open <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: checked remote connections are allowed

Comment: remote connections are allowed in script and server name is also correct

Comment: Does the instance `SQL18` exist?

Comment: it worked i wrote server name in CAPs doesnt know may be its case sensitive one more question PS1 need to be executed from powershell editor can you check this code its written in which language we write and save in .bat file and run from command prompt

Comment: REM GOTO END

erase %pathout%%job%*.txt > nul
erase %pathout%%job%*.suc > nul
erase %patherr%%job%*.err > nul

:main
REM 9/23/2010 - trying to implement DB maintenace jobs in Maestro that calls stored procedures directly
REM echo --- exec spBackupDB
REM set proc=umrdb..spBackupDB
REM call %osqlExeLocation% -E -d%dbname% -S%svr% -w%w% -n -b -Q"exec %proc%" -o"%pathout%%job%_%proc%.txt"
REM if errorlevel 1 (
REM set RetCode=1
REM goto endbad
REM )
REM 9/23/2010 - Comment-out END

Comment: i thought its powershell so was writing in ps and executing from comand prompt

Comment: Its bash. just (save with .bat or .cmd and) run in cmd.

Comment: thanks got it will write in bash and run was so confused thanks a lot for youir valuable info

Comment: You are welcome. Please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark symbol on the left. :)